# RethinkDB nested grouping

Tags: rethinkdb, reql

I have a RethinkDB table where documents look something like this:

```
[
  { "date": Mon Oct 05 2015 19:30:00 GMT+01:00, "category": 1, "name": "Alice" },
  { "date": Wed Oct 07 2015 14:00:00 GMT+01:00, "category": 2, "name": "Ben" },
  { "date": Mon Nov 16 2015 12:30:00 GMT+01:00, "category": 1, "name": "Charles" },
  { "date": Sun Nov 01 2015 22:15:00 GMT+01:00, "category": 1, "name": "Donald" }
  (...)
]
```

I'm trying to write a query in order to group my data by month/year, then (within each group) by category, and then perform some aggregation on the subgroups.

Based on the example given in the ReQL docs (https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/group/), this gives the first step:

```
r.table("seances").group([r.row("date").month(), r.row("date").year()])
```

I'm stuck here. Chaining with `group(r.row("category"))` gives an error message (Cannot call `group` on the output of `group`). Calling `ungroup` before the second `group` doesn't work either.

Any idea how it can be done? (ReQL looks very powerful but quite different from what I'm accustomed to with lodash...).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write `sequence.group(FIRST_GROUPING).ungroup().merge(function(row) { return {reduction: row('reduction').group(SECOND_GROUPING).ungroup()}; })`.

Comment: Thanks, it works! I'll have to figure what this does exactly, but you've put me on the right track. Just one comment, though: if I use `r.row()` in SECOND_GROUPING, I get an error message "cannot use row() in nested queries". Using a string with a single field name (eg "category") works, but what if I need to group by a field that is deeper than one level in the document?

Comment: Instead of `.group(r.row('a')('b'))` you can write `.group(function(row) { return row('a')('b'); })`.